# React/Redux: store is not updating between actions called from a single onClick event

Tags: redux, react-redux, state

#### Goal

To click the `next` button and dispatch two actions to the redux store that:

1. Firstly, update the `skipAmount` value.
2. And then use the updated `skipAmount` value to generate `apiQuery` (a string that is being used to make a request to a server).

#### Problem

The `skipAmount` value is not being updated between action 1 & 2

#### Example

I have created a CodeSandbox that clear demonstrates the issue that I am having. Notice that the `skipAmount` value is `100` (or one click event) ahead of `apiQuery`.
https://codesandbox.io/s/o2vvpwqo9

#### Code

*Index.js*

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { createStore } from "redux";

import App from "./App";
import reducer from "./reducer";

const store = createStore(reducer);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

*App.js*

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  ...state,
});

const queryGenerator = props => `www.apiExample.com?skipAmount=${props.skipAmount}`;

const ConnectedApp = props => (
  <div className="App">
    <button
      onClick={() => {
        props.dispatch({ type: 'SET_SKIP_AMOUNT_PLUS_100' });
        props.dispatch({ type: 'SET_API_QUERY', payload: queryGenerator(props) });
      }
      }
    >
      Next
    </button>
    <p>Skip amount on redux: {props.skipAmount}</p>
    <p>Query being generated: {props.apiQuery}</p>
  </div>
);

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ConnectedApp);
```

*reducer.js*

```
const reducerDefaultState = {
  skipAmount: 0,
  apiQuery: 'www.apiExample.com',
};

export default (state = reducerDefaultState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SET_SKIP_AMOUNT_PLUS_100':
      return {
        ...state,
        skipAmount: state.skipAmount + 100,
      };
    case 'SET_API_QUERY':
      return {
        ...state,
        apiQuery: action.payload,

      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In *App.js* `queryGenerator(props)` you are passing the unchanged props from the `onClick`.

props are'nt changing from `SET_SKIP_AMOUNT_PLUS_100` until rerender.

```
onClick={() => {
        props.dispatch({ type: 'SET_SKIP_AMOUNT_PLUS_100' });
        props.dispatch({ type: 'SET_API_QUERY', payload: queryGenerator(props) });
      }
```

In `'SET_SKIP_AMOUNT_PLUS_100'` you are changing the redux state. (not the current props in component),

and in `'SET_API_QUERY'` your are using the components props (not what's in redux) because props has'nt updated yet.

Comment: Thanks Jakob. Do you have any recommendations for how I could pass the updated props within a single onClick event?

Comment: No worries. 
You can achieve what you want by in p tag: 
`queryGenerator(props.apiQuery}`
If you want to save the value in the store, you could change the api_query in the same action as `SET_SKIP_AMOUNT_PLUS_100`

Comment: Thanks again, but I am afraid I don't think that really solves the issue. It is important for several parts of the application to make httpRequests based on an onClick event (and it won't always be as simple as this example), are there any other ways that you know of (such as middleware) to have component props update between actions?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you would like to achieve.
If you don't want to make multiple changes in the same action. 
And you want to use the changed store in the same onClick/function your only option is to send in a callback function to your actions. Which you really shouldn't have to do. 
Can you provide a real example, then I can better help you :)

Comment: Thanks Jakob, I really appreciate your help. Perhaps I haven't been clear enough. Imagine you have a search tool with a 'submit' button that loads 100 records at a time. To view more, the user has to click on the 'next' button at the bottom of the page. I would like the 'next' button to update the skipAmount by 100 and then make a query to the server with the updated skip amount. It is possible to click the 'next' button to skip the amount and then click the 'submit' button to make the request but that seems counter-intuitive to me. I will update the codesandbox to reflect what I mean.

Comment: So you want to perform a new fetch when clicking next with updated skipamount?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I would like to do.

Comment: Then I don't see the purpose of using redux. Unless you want to keep the result from that query in redux. If this is the case you can do: 
local state (in component) skipAmount. 
Then in your 
onClick={() => {
this.setState(skipAmount: this.state.skipAmount+100), 
() => this.props.dispatch(performFetch(this.state.skipAmount));
}}

Comment: You are an absolute legend Jakob! That is exactly what I was after. Thanks so much!!

Comment: Happy I could help!

Comment: Jacob is there anyway that I would be able to achieve the same result entirely with redux? I prefer using it to component state and also prefer using functional components over class based ones